# Alternative approach to io.ReadAll to store memory consumption and send a PUT Request with valid data

Tags: go, amazon-s3, parallel-processing

I will explain the scenario in detail,
there is on function which uses io.Pipe and returns a io.Reader with some data .
what i want to do is pass that data directly from that reader to my put request.
but when i pass directly to my api it give error : provided data is not matching with expected data because there is mismatch of offset value from where it is supposed to read.

My goal is to acheive this without storing the data in the memory.
URL which i am using to upload my content is a aws pre-signed url.

```
func ParallelPutRequest(chunkObject ChunkUrl, assetPath string, accessToken string, i int, bar *progressbar.ProgressBar, subtitleRelativeMap *sync.Map) error {
    var dataReader io.Reader
    if strings.Contains(assetPath, ".tar") {
        path := strings.TrimSuffix(assetPath, ".tar")
        dataReader, err := TraverseDirectory(path, subtitleRelativeMap)
        fmt.Println("reader", dataReader)
        //data,_=io.ReadAll(dataReader)
        //if err != nil {
        //  return err
        //}

    } else {
        file, err := os.Open(assetPath)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        dataReader := io.NewSectionReader(file, chunkObject.Offset, chunkObject.Size)
        //data, err = //io.ReadAll(dataReader)
        //if err != nil {
            //return err
        //}

        defer file.Close()

    }
    client := &http.Client{
        Timeout: 1 * time.Minute,
        Transport: &http.Transport{
            DisableKeepAlives: true,
        },
    }
    for attempt := 0; attempt < 4; attempt++ {
        // seeker, ok := dataReader.(io.Seeker)
        // if ok {
        //  _, err = seeker.Seek(0, io.SeekStart)
        //  if err != nil {
        //      return err
        //  }
        // }

        //reader:=bytes.NewReader(data)
        //fmt.Println("Reader inside request", reader)
        req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", chunkObject.UploadUrl, dataReader)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")

        resp, err := client.Do(req)
        if err != nil {
            if err, ok := err.(net.Error); ok && err.Timeout() {
                if attempt == 3 {
                    return err
                }
                continue
            } else if _, ok := err.(*url.Error); ok {
                if attempt == 3 {
                    return err
                }
                continue
            } else {
                slog.Error("upload.chunk.error", "attempt", attempt, "err", chunkObject.UploadUrl)
                return err
            }
        }
        responsbody, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        defer resp.Body.Close()
        if err == nil && resp.StatusCode == http.StatusOK {
            mutex.Lock()
            bar.Add(int(chunkObject.Size))
            mutex.Unlock()
            return nil

        }
        slog.Error("upload.chunk.error", "attempt", attempt, "response", string(responsbody))

        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    }
    return nil
}
```

In the above code traversedirectory function returns a io.Reader which i want to pass it on my put request and also in else condition io.NewSectionReader returns io.SectionReader
(when i do io.ReadAll (that converts all the data into byte slice and add it into bytes.NewReader() it works totally fine, concern is it will consume memory)
help will be appricieated.

I tried Io.ReadAll (which consume's memory)

Comment: please provide a complete, minimal reproduction.  There's a lot of stuff there that isn't relevant to your question.  A small http.Server implementation with a bytes.Buffer backend io.Reader would not be hard to build